# Right to left checkbox in MaterializeCSS instead of left to right

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm working with MaterializeCSS Framework and I want to use a checkbox in a form. In default, the checkbox is in the left of my label (Left To Right in default), but I want to change the place of the check box to before my label text.

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" class="" />
    <label class="right-align"  for="rememberme">Remember me</label>
</p>
```

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when check box not checked

```
[type="checkbox"]+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(.filled-in)+label:after
{
left:175px;
}
```

when the checkbx checked

```
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before
{
left:175px;
}
```

Cascade Property Helped.

Answer (score 2):

i found a better solution

```css
[type="checkbox"] + label::before, [type="checkbox"]:not(.filled-in) + label::after {
    right: 0;
}

[type="checkbox"] + label {
    padding-right: 26px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    right: 8px;
    left: 0;
}
.filled-in[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    right: 9px;
    left: unset;
}
.filled-in[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
}
.filled-in[type="checkbox"] + label::before, .filled-in[type="checkbox"] + label::after {
    right: -1px;
}
.filled-in[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label::before {
    right: 10px;
}
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label {
    padding-right: 26px;
}
[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    padding-right: 26px;
}
[type="radio"] + label::before, [type="radio"] + label::after {
    right: 0;left:unset;
}
label::before, [type="radio"] + label::after {
    right: 0;left:unset;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some tests, this is what worked for me:

I made the checkbox position to the right, and the label padding right until I felt it was position in the right position

in css file:

```
body{ direction: rtl }

/*  align the checkbox to the right    */
[type="checkbox"]+label:before, [type="checkbox"]+label:after{        
  right: 0px !important;
}

/*  align the v in the center of the checkbox    */
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked+label:before{
  right: 11px !important;
}

/*  align the label left to the checkbox   */
[type="checkbox"]+label{
  padding-right: 27px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this might also do the trick:  (the right answer didnt work for me well), that did..

```
    [type="checkbox"]+label {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 35px;
    }
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in:not(:checked)+label:after {
        right: 0;
    }
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked+label:after {
        right: 0;
    }
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked+label:before {
        right: 10px;
    }
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in+label::before,
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in+label::after {
        right: 10px;
    }
    [type="checkbox"].filled-in:not(:checked)+label::before {
        right: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    direction: rtl;
}
/*CheckBox R2L*/
[type="checkbox"] + span:not(.lever) {
    padding-right: 27px;
}
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:not(:checked) + span:not(.lever):before, 
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):before {
    right: 10px;
}

[type="checkbox"].filled-in:not(:checked) + span:not(.lever):after,
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):after {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Materialize CSS-->
    <link href="~/css/ghpages-materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <p class="right">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" checked="checked" />
            <span>أرسل لي إيميل عند إضافة إجابة</span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <!--Materialize js-->
    <script src="/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

[Click here to see the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPDAQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks